# How to Add this functionality to Qt 4.6 embedded linux QWS ( Qt Windowing System)?

Tags: qt, embedded-linux

I want to send an event to an Qt Application named "Video Player" from Qt Server when any of the running application 's any widget gets Paint Event.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the other applications and have DBus available on your device, I would suggest using it for this purpose.  You can install an event handler in each of the other applications that emits a signal over DBus, and your video player application can subscribe to that signal and do whatever it needs to when it gets the signal.

I doubt that you'll be able to get paint events from the QWS, however.  It probably just tells the given application what region/rectangle needs refreshed, and the application finds the appropriate widgets and sends them the paint events.  I would be surprised if the QWS had any knowledge of the individual widgets in a given application.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for answer, I think the only way is to patch QScreen ( ExposeRegion function) and through IPC ( DBus ) notify video player.